# How to populate a Gravity Form checkbox with a query string

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I can populate a gravity form text field that has a parameter name of 'textfield' with a query string like

```
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value
```

But I would also like to be able to populate a checkbox, i.e check a box. However, checkboxes are not mentioned in the Gravity Forms documentation "Dynamically Populating a Field".

My checkbox is called 'flags' and has choices with names of 'box1' and 'box2', so I tried

```
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value&flags.box1=true
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value&flags.box1=1
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value&flags[box1]=true
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value&flags[box1]=1
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value&flags=box1
```

But I cannot get a box to check.   Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Went and looked at the code.

To set a single checkbox (or value in a list) use

```
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value&flags=box1
```

To set multiple values the code is set up to use syntax like:

```
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value&flags=box1|box2
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value&flags=box1%C7box2
```

However, in the gravity form source there is a test for a list, that also needs to test for a checkbox.  In `forms_model.php`, function `get_parameter_value` I changed the statement

```
if ( ! empty( $value ) && RGFormsModel::get_input_type( $field ) == 'list' )
```

to

```
if ( ! empty( $value ) && (RGFormsModel::get_input_type( $field ) == 'list' || 
      RGFormsModel::get_input_type( $field ) == 'checkbox' ))
```

Then it all works!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax was just a bit off. It's not that well documented. You need to use commas.

```
https://www.example.com/formpage/?textfield=value&flags=box1,box2
```

[image]